# Using System Fonts In WaveEngine

Tags: c#

I ended up maintaining some C# code using the WaveEngine to display some 3D stuff.
I'm using the `TextComponent` class and the `TextRenderer3D` class to display the text. The text gets displayed. So far so good...

What I want to do now is to change the font at runtime (the user should be able to change font, text, color, etc.). I would like to use the system fonts, so I don't have to deliver any fonts with our software.

The `TextComponent` class has a property `FontPath` but when I assign something to that property the text is no longer displayed. From what I've read so far I'm supposed to add the fonts as resources into my project and reference that resource.

Is there a way how I can use the fonts installed on the machine instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some feedback from WaveEngine guys.

With version 2.4.1 it's not possible to load system fonts at runtime and it's not going to be implemented for version 2 since they are working on version 3 now. It doesn't seem to be on the road map for version 3 either.

The way it works is to use the wave editor tool provided by WaveEngine and to import the fonts as resources into your project.
But you have to import it then for every font size that you plan to use, for bold, italic and so on. And of course you have to license that font if you deliver it with your software.